# Set sandbox flags to functionrunner to allow downloads or popups

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

is there a possibility to set flags like allow-downloads or allow-popups in slate? i would like to generate small PDF files with custom functions, but since the code runs sandboxed the browser prevents opening popups or downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i asked this question the new event action `slate.downloadBlob` got added. With this action its possible to create a pdf file as a blob and trigger the download (for example with the jsPDF library).

Comment: Thank you for coming back and answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible and as is a side effect of the sandboxing. The reason for the sandboxing, is to avoid non sandboxed code from pushing data outside of foundry, which would facilitate rogue actors to bypass security settings and steal data.